# cannot access php array with index?

Tags: php, arrays

Following is my code; i didnot get problem what's wrong with it;

```
$units=explode(";",$course->unitinfo);
foreach($units as $unit)
{
    $unitinfo=explode("|",$unit);
    echo'<tr>
            <td>'.$unitinfo[1].'</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>';
}
```

Here string **$course->unitinfo** comes with two delimiters **first is ;** and contains info of one row and second delimiter is **|** pipe sign; first explode works fine; second explode generates error with undefined offset, if print it with print_r is shows-

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => Mechanics
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 1,2
    [4] => 3,1
)
```

and the problem is cant access via its index - $unitinfo[1];
where i am wrong

Comment: can you print $units array in question?

Comment: `var_dump($unit, $unitinfo);`

Comment: It does feel like unit is not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check for occurence of `|` to avoid 'undefined offset' warnings in your script:

```
$testString = 'test|1;test|2;test3';

$units=explode(";",$testString);
foreach($units as $unit)
{
    $value = '';
    if (strpos($unit, '|') !== false) {
        $unitinfo=explode("|",$unit);
        $value = $unitinfo[1];
    } else {
        $value='No pipe found';
    }


    echo'<tr>
            <td>'.$value.'</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>';
}
```

Will show:

```
1 2 No pipe found
```